# ID selector for child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When we have a unique parent element and there are some different(unrelated) children in it which would be the preferred way to define and apply styles?

```css
#parentCon
{
  declarations...
}
/* 1. Following is unnecessary, even looks somewhat weird 
but it might give a clue about relation to developer. */
#parentCon #child1
{
  declarations...
}


/* 2. Apply directly to child by its id. 
They are defined consecutively so developer have a clue 
about their relation, indentation will also help. */
#parentCon
{
  declarations...
}
  #child1
  {
    declarations...
  }

/* 3. Use a class for child although child is unique, 
there will be no other instances of it. */
#parentCon .child1
{
  declarations...
}
```

```html
<div id="parentCon">
  <div id="child1">
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parentCon">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it sensible to use class selector although there will be only one instance? What about wasted performance when class used?
I am trying to learn your use-case ideas about using IDs for children here so this is not about a specific parent-child problem.

Comment: Is it there any update?

Answer (score 1):

I would not think about performance in this case, browsers are really good in optimizing that.

The big difference is reusability.

Use ID if that element is unique in the document. Use class if you want to reuse the style.

`#parentCon #child1` is interesting though. It may look strange, but has a meaning. Apply this style to `#child1` only if it is child of `#parentCon`. If you are going to generate the page dynamically and move `#child1` in the page can be an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` only to define per-page, application-wise (JS) unique selector (remember that you can only have one element in DOM with the same id value).

In this case `#id1 #id2` is useless and difficult to use it more than once. `#id2` would be the very same, but again, I'd use class-based styling.

For example: `.myModule .myElement`, where `myModule` is the parent of a complex object, let's say a carousel, an image frame or whatever, and `myElement` is the particular element inside this `ecosystem`.

Answer (score 0):

id is a unique identifier, if you wanna use it more than once then use class not id.

Here is a good guide:
[CSS Selectors Guide](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
Basically you are looking for:

> p:nth-child(2)
>   Selects every
>
> element that is the second child of its parent

replace # with .

> .parentCon:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(1)
>   Will be the first div of the second parentCon

Good Luck

Comment: If some other unrelated child added anywhere in the parent those rules need to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

How about using simple child selectors, such as

1. `#parentCon div {declarations}`
2. `#parentCon > div {declarations}`

Big difference between the two...

1. Will select any and ALL descendants that are div's within `#parentCon`. This includes div's within div's.

   ```
   <div id="parentCon"> 
    <div class="random"> 
     <div class="child-of-random"> 
     </div> 
    </div> 
   </div>
   ```

   In other words, the declarations you declare will apply to `"child-of-random"` as well as `"random"`.
2. Will only select DIRECT descendant div's of `#parentCon`, so only `"random"`.

   This allows you to target the children programmatically. What's more, if you want to target individual children, you can use the `:first-child` / `:last-child` selectors. In addition, you can use the `nth-child` selector to target specific children.

Great resource for more information on nth-child selectors: https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: When classes used, its fine but when we need to add some other unrelated child it would break those pseudo class rules or those div, > div rules.

Comment: You can still target specific children individually if need be... Give the child in question a class and you can target the class name. Doing this means you can overrule properties that are declared within the parent's styling, or the styling for its children.